# Multiple comparisons when preforming a t-test and Mann-Whitney U test

Tags: t-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, false-discovery-rate

I have 90 proteins(column) and about 170 samples(rows) with data. The data describes protein levels for 90 different proteins.

Every samples is also in a group, A and B. I would like to preform a t-test and see if there is any different between A and B for every protein. If i would do a t-test for every protein I know I have to adjust the p-value using Bonferroni or false discovery rate or some other method.

Prior to the test I check every protein to see if it follows a normal distribution and even though the t-test is robust for normallity some of the proteins are not close to a normal distribution. So for those protein will i preform a Mann-Whitney U test (or some other non parametric test).

**My question is then if i should adjust the p-values for the test with t-test and Mann-Whitney together or not?**

Hope you guys understand my question otherwise I will try to clarify it.

Comment: I would think you should adjust the p-values together. I am thinking about this conceptually, not statistically, so someone else may feel different, but whether you use a t-test or a Mann-Whitney there's still some definite Type-I error risk. Since you're performing all these tests together, it shouldn't matter which one you use for any particular protein, the risk is still there for each protein. Sorry, probably not the answer you were hoping for.

Comment: I am thinking in the same way you are. But am not sure. Thanks for the imput.

Comment: Hi @Princess. It's usually a bad idea to select a parametric or nonparametric test based on the outcome of your normality assessment. Either you should choose a test for each protein a priori (i.e. without looking at the data) or use the same test for all proteins.

Comment: @amoeba What would that mean (to choose a test for each protein a priori) - the multiple comparison problem still holds. I am quite in the same situation, as I chose to perform parametric and non-parametric tests on different variables depending on their distribution.